# Updating values in Core Data leads to duplicate entries in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, editing

I am trying to update the values from core data for my iPad application. Unfortunately each time I update the data, it creates a duplicate entry.

I coded below code which takes the parameters that contain the values and tries to update. But unfortunately it creates a duplicate entry rather than updating the existing entry.

```
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Project", in: context)
        let newProject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        let projectID = 1

        newProject.setValue(projectID, forKey: "projectID")
        newProject.setValue(projectName, forKey: "projectName")
        newProject.setValue(projectFinalDueDate, forKey: "projectFinalDueDate")
        newProject.setValue(ProjectNotes, forKey: "projectNotes")
        newProject.setValue(projectPriority, forKey: "projectPriority")
        newProject.setValue(projectAddedDate, forKey: "projectAddedDate")

        do {
            try context.save()
            showMessage(message: "Successfully update project", messageType: "success")
        } catch {
            showMessage(message: "Failed to update project", messageType: "error")
        }
```

I am sorry if the keywords that I have used are wrong and please do note that I am a newbie in Core Data, I began to use it like a few days ago.

Appreciate if someone could help me solve this issue

[Please find the screen recording of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rWmP.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You create a new object here

```
let newProject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
```

so it'll add a new object , you need to use a predicate and update the retrieved value according to some primary key then save the context like

```
    //As we know that container is set up in the AppDelegates so we need to refer that container.
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    
    //We need to create a context from this container
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Project")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "projectID  = %d",1)
    do
    {
        let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

         guard let newProject = test.first else { return }
            // update here 
           
           try managedContext.save()                
        }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Oh, so if i use the projectID as the primary key it should do yeah?

Comment: Thank you very much, also can you please tell me what does `"%d", 1` do?

Comment: it's supposed to retrieve object with `projectID ` = 1 so you can update it , see here for a complete CRUD demo https://github.com/AnkurVekariya/CoreDataSwiftDemo

Comment: Oh okay, how would the predicate be if I want to dynamically get the `projectID` after doing a sort according to the date added?

Comment: I tried the code you typed above, when I try to set the value using `newProject` I get the following error `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'setValue'`. If I try to set the value via `managedContext` I am getting the following exception `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObjectContext 0x6000005211d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key projectName.'`

Comment: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key projectName` make sure there is `projectName` property inside the model

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I just solved it by getting the `NSObject` via segue and using that object `.setValue(VariableName, ForKey: "")`

Comment: key can't be `""`

Comment: Was just using it as an example :) The real one doesn't have the `ForKey` as `""`

Comment: you should only set keys for values that exists inisde the entity